# Comparing two arrays with array_diff

Tags: php, arrays, api

I have the following code and am trying to compare two array's with array_diff however I keep getting no results. I not sure if it matters, but there are many fields in the array and I really only want to compare 1 field...is this possible? what am I missing?

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("http://ebird.org/ws1.1/data/obs/region/recent?rtype=subnational1&r=US-AZ&back=7&fmt=json");
$json2 = file_get_contents("http://ebird.org/ws1.1/data/obs/region/recent?rtype=subnational1&r=US-NV&back=7&fmt=json");

$array1 = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$array2 = json_decode($json2, TRUE);

if ( $array1 == $array2 ) {
echo 'There are no differences';
}else 
var_dump(array_diff($array2, $array1));
echo 'they are different';

?>
```

Comment: Did you read the manual on equality comparison for arrays and on `array_diff`?

Comment: Why not compare the JSON as a string. If they are equal then the array/object is going to be the same when they are decoded anyhow. [`strcmp`](http://php.net/strcmp).

Comment: What do you mean with comparing only one (1) field? $arr1['field_x1'] === $arr2['filed_x2']?

Comment: Besides, you should always get a "they are different" because your else part misses brackets {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to check the arrays against each other:

```
$Array_1 = array (1,2,3,4,5);
$Array_2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

print_r(array_diff($Array_1,$Array_2));
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
)
```

Whereas:

```
 print_r(array_diff($Array_2,$Array_1));
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [5] => 6
)
```

So this might be a solution:

```
function ArrayDiff ($Array_1, $Array_2){
    $Compare_1_To_2 = array_diff($Array_1,$Array_2);
    $Compare_2_To_1 = array_diff($Array_2,$Array_1);
    $Difference_Array = array_merge($Compare_1_To_2,$Compare_2_To_1);
    return $Difference_Array;

}

print_r(ArrayDiff($Array_1,$Array_2));
```

Which will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
)
```

---

Putting this into an if statement:

```
$Differences = ArrayDiff($Array_2,$Array_1);
if (count($Differences) > 0){
    echo 'There Are Differences Between The Array:';
    foreach ($Differences AS $Different){
        echo "<br>".$Different;
    }
```

All the examples and code is based off the arrays at the start ($Array_1 and $Array_2)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $po_line_array=array();
    $po_line_clone_array=array();

    foreach($cart->line_items as $line_no => $po_line)
         $po_line_array[$line_no]=$po_line->labdip_details_id;
       print_r($po_line_array,1);
    foreach($cart->line_items_clone as $line_no_clone => $po_line_clone)
         $po_line_clone_array[$line_no_clone]=$po_line_clone->labdip_details_id;
       print_r($po_line_clone_array,1);

     $result=array_diff($po_line_clone_array,$po_line_array);
     print_r($result,1);
```

Output:

```
 Array ( [0] => 101 )

    Array ( [0] => 101 [1] => 103 )

    Array ( [1] => 103 )
```

Comment: "Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Comments would help create searchable content.
"